# Batch Apex: Invalid field StageName for OpportunityHistory

Tags: batch, error, opportunity-history

In my SalesForce managed package I have a Batch Apex job that queries OpportunityHistory and does some post-processing (basically serialize them and posts to external Web Service)

When I schedule and execute this batch in my development organization everything works fine, however after packaging and installing on test org I get following error - **Invalid field StageName for OpportunityHistory**

It's interesting however that the similar code works completely fine for Opportunity object both in developer console in dev org and in installed package on test org.

In test org I do not see any logs for installed package so it's hard to predict why this happens. It's important to notice that package is installed with *unrestricted access*

It's obvious that **StageName** is a valid field for **OpportunityHistory** - so I cannot gues what can be the cause of this error.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Fyi, as the creator of the managed package, you can get detailed logging turned on for it via a support request to Salesforce.

Comment: Quite strange indeed.. I assume you set up a sales process on the test org? And what is the exact piece of code causing the error?